# group by base on 2 element

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

equal this

select id,name,  count(*) from  table group by   id, name

what is in linq???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of entity framework it is better to return computed projection directly from SQL:

```
var query = from x in context.YourEntities
            group x by new { x.ID, x.Name } into y
            select new 
                {
                    y.Key.ID,
                    y.Key.Name,
                    y.Count()
                };
```

This will do `Count` in database and reduce amount of transferred data.

Answer (score 0):

```
var groups = table.GroupBy(elt => new {ID = elt.ID, Name = elt.name});
foreach (var group in groups)
{
    var ID = group.Key.ID;
    var name = group.Key.Name;
    var count = group.Count();
...
}
```